# Jquery created page transitions - make them linkable

Tags: jquery, html, animation, transition

I have a client who wants a very specific type of site.

I've created a demo for her which can be seen here: http://hbs.com.ro/march/

She insisted on having the page transitions that you see in the demo for the main content, so I worked some jQuery and made that happen. But since all the content has to be hidden on the same page for this to work, I can't link between the pages. For example I can't just send someone straight to the contact page by adding "/contact" at the end, cause there is no actual "/contact" page.

Any suggestions for keeping the way the site behaves but also with working links?

I already tried working with the :target selector, but that causes scrolling problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). If I were you I would use ajax and have a look to that.